# Remote plugin activation hook

Tags: plugins, activation, remote

I am remote activating plugins using `update_option('active_plugins,'some_plugins');` It works fine except one thing: if some plugins have to create some tables using `register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'activate');` it won't create them.

When I'm activating plugins normally in `wp-admin/plugins.php` it works fine. Any ideas how to remote execute this activation hook or maybe there is different way to better plugin activation?

Answer (score 1):

Use `activate_plugin()` instead:

```
activate_plugin( $plugin, $redirect = '', $network_wide = false, $silent = false )
```

You need just the first parameter, the same value as in the option.

This function will call the necessary actions:

```
if ( ! $silent ) {
    do_action( 'activate_plugin', $plugin, $network_wide );
    do_action( 'activate_' . $plugin, $network_wide );
}
```

Note: depending on where you call activate_plugin function you might need to add this:

```
 include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
```

Comment: Hi toscho. I'm using xml-rpc calls to work on wordpress. `activate_plugin()` method isn't accessible by it. Calling `do_action('activate_plugin','plugin/plugin.php',false)` gives nothing. Only way I see for now is direct create tables in database. Or maybe You have another ideas?

Comment: @bigwolk Have you tried to [extend XML RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending) to get access to the function?

Comment: I'm using [extended api](http://wordpress.org/plugins/extended-xml-rpc-api/) plugin to access almost all methods in wordpress.